# Sandbox mode will not disable - app cannot be seen on page

Tags: facebook, sandbox

I am trying to help my sister with her facebook business page.  She created an app some time ago, but did not disable sandbox mode, so it has never been visible.

She made me an administrator of the page, and the app.  But when I try to disable sandbox mode to make the app visible on her page, I get the following error message:

Error
There was a problem saving your changes. Please try again later.

Before this error, I believe facebook directed me to set up a category for the app in the app details, where "other" had been selected.  I tried changing this to "app for pages" but it didn't help.

I created another app some time ago where all the same fields are filled in as with my sister's app, and had no trouble disabling sandbox.

I do no understand why facebook is not allowing me to disable sandbox and make the app live.  I have googled this question but been unable to find an answer.